# Python Celery workflow error handling stop execution

Tags: python, celery, celery-task

I have a work flow that looks like this: [image]

I would like to check the status of each chain during the Combine task and stop if there are any errors, stop execution.  But if no errors, go head to Format Results task.  I'm having trouble getting the errors in Task 1, 2, etc to propogate to the Combine Task.
Is there a method to do this in Celery? I can do on_error callback / link_error in each Tasks but how to propogate that to the Combine Task?

Comment: Ok, my strategy for this now is to store each Tasks result in a database and then in the Combine task, query all the results and decide to proceed to Format Results or Fail.